# Function parameter as argument in an R function

Tags: r, confidence-interval, function, credible-interval

I am attempting to write a general function to calculate coverage probabilities for interval estimation of Binomial proportions in R. I intend to do this for a variety of confidence interval methods e.g. Wald, Clopper-Pearson, HPD intervals for varying priors.

Ideally, I would like there to be one function, that can take, as an argument, the method that should be used to calculate the interval. My question then: how can I include a function as an argument in another function?

As an example, for the Exact Clopper-Pearson interval I have the following function:

```
# Coverage for Exact interval
ExactCoverage <- function(n) {
p <- seq(0,1,.001)
x <- 0:n

# value of dist
dist <- sapply(p, dbinom, size=n, x=x)

# interval
int <- Exact(x,n)

# indicator function
ind <- sapply(p, function(x) cbind(int[,1] <= x & int[,2] >= x))

list(coverage = apply(ind*dist, 2, sum), p = p)
}
```

Where Exact(x,n) is just a function to calculate the appropriate interval. I would like to have

```
Coverage <- function(n, FUN, ...)
...
# interval
int <- FUN(...)
```

so that I have one function to calculate the coverage probabilities rather than a separate coverage function for each method of interval calculation. Is there a standard way to do this? I have not been able to find an explanation.

Thanks,
James

Comment: You might want to read https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functional-programming

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In R, a function can be provided as a function argument. The syntax matches the one of non-function objects.

Here is an example function.

```
myfun <- function(x, FUN) {
  FUN(x)
}
```

This function applies the function `FUN` to the object `x`.

A few examples with a vector including the numbers from 1 to 10:

```
vec <- 1:10 

> myfun(vec, mean)
[1] 5.5
> myfun(vec, sum)
[1] 55
> myfun(vec, diff)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This is not limited to built-in functions, but works with any function:

```
> myfun(vec, function(obj) sum(obj) / length(obj))
[1] 5.5

mymean <- function(obj){
  sum(obj) / length(obj)
}
> myfun(vec, mymean)
[1] 5.5
```

Comment: How would you add function parameters for the passed function "FUN"?

Comment: This is really late @Christian, but for others:

```
myfun <- function(x, FUN, ...) {
  FUN(x, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also store a function name as a character variable, and call it with do.call()

```
> test = c(1:5)
> do.call(mean, list(test))
[1] 3
> 
> func = 'mean'
> do.call(func, list(test))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hadley's text](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html) gives a great (and simple) example:

```
randomise <- function(f) f(runif(1e3))

randomise(mean)
#> [1] 0.5059199
randomise(mean)
#> [1] 0.5029048
randomise(sum)
#> [1] 504.245
```